# Unable to add an API to Azure apim Product using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm trying to create an Azure apim Product and add an API to it using Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement v1.1.0 nuget for.NET,
I'm able to create a product but I'm not able to add an API to that product.

This is how I created the product:

```
var data = new ApiManagementProductData()
{
    DisplayName = productName,
    IsSubscriptionRequired = true,
    State = ApiManagementProductState.Published,
};
var products = _apiManagementServiceResource.GetApiManagementProducts();

var productResource = await products.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, productName, data);
```

There is no Apis field on the ApiManagementProductData type.

This is how it can be done on the Azure portal (API management):
[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdyDg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given code to add an API to the Product.

```cs
using Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement;
using Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement.Models;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;


TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();

ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

string subscriptionId = "{subscriptionId}";
string resourceGroupName = "{resourceGroupName}";
string serviceName = "{serviceName}";
ResourceIdentifier apiManagementServiceResourceId = ApiManagementServiceResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, serviceName);
ApiManagementServiceResource apiManagementService = client.GetApiManagementServiceResource(apiManagementServiceResourceId);


var productName = "Test_Product";
var data = new ApiManagementProductData()
{
    DisplayName = "Test_Product",
    IsSubscriptionRequired = true,
    State = ApiManagementProductState.Published,
};
var products = apiManagementService.GetApiManagementProducts();
var productResource_created = await products.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, productName, data);

ApiManagementProductResource productResource = productResource_created.Value;
ApiManagementProductData productData = productResource.Data;

ApiManagementProductResource apiManagementProduct = client.GetApiManagementProductResource(productData.Id);
ApiCollection collection = apiManagementService.GetApis();

// invoke the operation
string api_name = "echo-api";
ApiResource api_data = await collection.GetAsync(api_name);
ApiData resourceData = api_data.Data;
ProductApiData result = await apiManagementProduct.CreateOrUpdateProductApiAsync(resourceData.Name);

Console.WriteLine($"Successfully Added: {result.Name}");
```

API added successfully to the product.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!
can you please share a link to the docs? I couldn't find any C# examples

Comment: You can find all the sample code here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement_1.1.0/sdk/apimanagement/Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement/samples/Generated/Samples

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for such samples for hours, they make things much more clear, do you know where I can find such docs to interact with the access control of an APImanagement product? (didn't see it in that link)

Comment: its present in the same link for Productcollection like https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement_1.1.0/sdk/apimanagement/Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_ApiManagementProductCollection.cs